# Difference between ArtifactSet and Filters

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to exclude some classes that come from a dependency in a fat jar and includes things like slf4j (that cause dependency conflicts).

I've looked at the maven-shade-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). I first tried to use the artifactSet param, but it didn't work by using `jar tf myjar.jar`. The dependencies I was trying to exclude were still there.

I was able to solve it using the filters param as described in the docs: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html

It is not obvious to me the difference between these two. Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: What does it mean: ` but it didn't work` ? Error messages ? Log files ? The pom configuration you have tried etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html), `<artifactSet>` includes or excludes whole jars, while `<filters>` includes or excludes classes within a jar.